# refresh fragment UI from fragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentpageradapter

I want to change a ImageView in fragment(that create in code), from FragmentActivity. (there is no fragment and tag in XML).

MainActivity that extends from FragmentActivity and implements from GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks:

```
...
FragmentAdapter mAdapter;
ViewPager mPager;
...

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ...
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(fm);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ...}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint){
//*** I want to change a ImageView on Fragment1 here
}
```

FragmentAdapter that extends from FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
...
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos){
// String name = makeFragmentName(R.id.mainPager, pos);
// Fragment fragmentObject = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
Fragment fragmentObject = null;

switch(pos){
    case 0:
        fragmentObject = new Fragment1();
        break;
    ...
}

return fragmentObject;
}
...

//private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, iont index){
    //return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
//}
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486952/get-id-of-textview-in-fragment-from-fragmentactivity-in-viewpager) topic for change a element in fragment, from fragmentActivity:

Fragment1 that extends from Fragment:

```
private ImageView IMGThisImageShouldChange = null;

public View onCreateView(...){
    IMGThisImageShouldChange = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.TargetImage);
    ...
}

public void changeImageView(int resourceId){
    IMGThisImageShouldChange.setImageResource(resouirceId);
}
```

A comment line in this topic says:

> //Do not create new object each time you set text. Use the same
>   fragment object which you use for view pager.

So how can i access to fragmentObject from MainActivity, to call changeImageView method?

If i should find fragment via tag, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374170/how-to-set-a-fragment-tag-by-code) topic, where i should set tag and how to find?

Comment: jgriffsta's answer is right. The tag it will be null in the `onCreate()` method(as fragment transactions are asynchronous but it should be ok if you use that code in the `onConnected()` callback.

Comment: @Luksprog You right. that's work. But i changed my technique to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager. But in getItem() i don't have any idea about newInstance().  1-What is that function's codes? 2-Which techniques are better?

Comment: 1. it's a static method that returns an object of the class in which it was declared(it's a common java pattern) 2. The code you linked to is better because it doesn't rely on some tag that could be changed(breaking your app)

Comment: @Luksprog I don't get point of 1! Does my question's getItem(){...} is right? Or should i check if fragmentObject is null then create it, by makeFragmentName? Or new technique handle this?(this means: null, recreate, restore,...)

Comment: Your `getItem()` method is correct, in there you need to return a fragment object(which you can do either by instantiating the class or using that `newInstance()` static method).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345129/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cant-change-tag-of-fragment/59835511#59835511

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So obviously adjust for your specific needs, but this is what I use for my Application.

```
 Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + mPager.getCurrentItem());
    if(frag!=null&&mPager.getCurrentItem()==0)
        {
           ((Fragment1) frag).changeImageView(1);
        }
```

Comment: I changed my technique to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager ;;;;; But thanks a lot and your answer is right anyway.